# Get Window throws null pointer exception when referenced from another class

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, touch, listener

I am using PDFViewer in a Fragment within Android Studio. Library found here: https://github.com/barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer

This library works fine when I allow the library to handle all the touch events, but I want to hide the system toolbars in my activity (SingleTouchImageViewActivity) when an onSingleTapConfirmed event occurs. Since the OnTouchListener is in another class (DragPinchManager), I am unable to reference the Window within my Activity to flag fullscreen. I get a null pointer exception.

```
2020-04-28 19:00:02.952 22265-22265/com.biggerbytes.gospeltruth E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.biggerbytes.gospeltruth, PID: 22265
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.Window.addFlags(int)' on a null object reference
    at com.biggerbytes.gospeltruth.SingleTouchImageViewActivity.hideSystemUI(SingleTouchImageViewActivity.java:1109)
    at com.biggerbytes.gospeltruth.SingleTouchImageViewActivity.runFullScreenCheck(SingleTouchImageViewActivity.java:900)
    at com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.DragPinchManager.onSingleTapConfirmed(DragPinchManager.java:80)
    at android.view.GestureDetector$GestureHandler.handleMessage(GestureDetector.java:316)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7073)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:964)
```

Here's the Code in DragPinchManager:

```
Context stivaContext;
```

@Override
    public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) {

```
    SingleTouchImageViewActivity singleTouchImageViewActivity = new SingleTouchImageViewActivity();
    stivaContext = singleTouchImageViewActivity.getStivaContext();
    singleTouchImageViewActivity.hideSystemUI(stivaContext);
    return true;
}
```

And here's the corresponding code in SingleTouchImageViewActivity:

```
Context stiva;    

 @Override
public View onCreateView(String name, Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {

    stiva = context;

    if(FullScreenMode) {
        hideSystemUI(stiva);
    }


    public void hideSystemUI(Context context) {
    FullScreenMode = true;
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 19) { // lower api
        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else {
        //for new api versions.
    //    View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
        int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY;
        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
    }

    toolbarTop.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    toolbarBottom.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

How can I fix my nullPointerException and hide my navigation on SingleTapConfirmed?
Thank You!

Update: Here's what I have done. I set a context variable in SingleTouchImageViewActivity named stiva. I set it when onCreateView is called. After the pdf loads, I do a single tap on my pdf. DragPinchManager calls a method to get the context from SingleTouchImageViewActivity, and then calls hideSystemUI(stiva) passing in the context that it received from SingleTouchImageViewActivity when the pdf triggered the single tap event.
For some reason, stiva is null when DragPinchManager tries to reference it. Can you help me with that?

Also, I am not sure how to use the context that I pass into hideSystemUI().

Here's what I would think it would be, but I think I'm way off...

```
SingleTouchImageViewActivity.context.getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Comment: `new SingleTouchImageViewActivity()` -- **never** create an instance of an activity yourself. Whatever object contains your `onSingleTapConfirmed()` method needs to have the existing instance of `SingleTouchImageViewActivity` passed into it, so you can hold onto it in a field and then call methods on it.

Comment: @CommonsWare Can you give me an example of how to pass in the existing instance of SingleTouchImageViewActivity?

Comment: [In this sample](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-jetpack-java/-/tree/v0.8/RecyclerViewBasics/src/main/java/com/commonsware/jetpack/samplerj/recyclerview) from [this book](https://commonsware.com/Jetpack), my activity passes a `LayoutInflater` to my `ColorAdapter`. I could just as easily have had my activity pass the activity itself to my `ColorAdapter`, and the `ColorAdapter` could have called `getLayoutInflater()` on the activity itself.

Comment: @CommonsWare Can you take a look at the question again? I updated it and also my code. I'm not sure if I need to be passing the activity itself or if I'm needing to pass context. Thanks for your help. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Your code seems to be not passing anything. Instead, you seem to be creating a possible memory leak, by putting a `Context` in a `static` field. Presumably, your activity is creating an instance of `DragPinchManager`. If so, pass the `Activity` into `DragPinchManager` via its constructor, such as [how this constructor accepts a `LayoutInflater`](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-jetpack-java/-/blob/v0.8/RecyclerViewBasics/src/main/java/com/commonsware/jetpack/samplerj/recyclerview/ColorAdapter.java#L27-31).

Comment: You can see [here](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-jetpack-java/-/blob/v0.8/RecyclerViewBasics/src/main/java/com/commonsware/jetpack/samplerj/recyclerview/MainActivity.java#L37) the corresponding code in the activity that creates the `ColorAdapter` and passes in the `LayoutInflater`. In your case, it would be an `Activity` or `Context` instead of a `LayoutInflater`, but the same basic concept applies.

Comment: I am confused. Are you modifying the library?

Comment: @CommonsWare

I got the library here: https://github.com/barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer

PDFView creates an instance of DragPinchManager.

DragPinchManager dragPinchManager = new DragPinchManager(this, animationManager);

I don't have the animation manager in SingleTouchImageViewActivity, so I attemped to create an instance of PDFView from my activity and pass in the activity. From there I intended to pass the activity on to DragPinchManager. When I try to add Activity as the 3rd paramater, my layout file throws an error. I'll post the error below.

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.PDFView.<init> [class android.content.Context, interface android.util.AttributeSet]

Comment: Yes, I am. It is under the Apache 2.0 license.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213354/discussion-between-dsallee-and-commonsware).

Comment: You may want to contact the author of the library for advice, then. Your error suggests that you removed or modified the parameter list for `PDFView` itself. If you wish to use `PDFView` in a layout resource, `PDFView` needs to still have its `public PDFView(Context context, AttributeSet set)` constructor.

Comment: Okay, is there a way to add more than one constructor or call another method within PDFView without having to pass in context and an Attribute set?

Comment: I was thinking that you were creating `DragPinchManager` yourself, as I was working solely off of code in your question. If all you need is a `Context`, call `getContext()` on `pdfView` in the `DragPinchManager` -- you will see a few examples of this already in the class. If you need the `Activity` or some sort of callback supplied by the activity, you could add a method to `PDFView` that accepts the callback and calls a method that you add to `DragPinchManager` that saves the callback in a field for later use.

Answer (score 0):

As @CommonsWare said, never create an instance of activity yourself.

This crash because you use the window object and your activity has no window!

To fix this issue, launch your activity using Intent

```
@Override
public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) {
    Intent i = new Intent(this, SingleTouchImageViewActivity.class);

    startActivity(i);
}
```

And then inside `onCreate` of `SingleTouchImageViewActivity` call `hideSystemUI` method